# I seem no longer to be a sudoer

Tags: sudo

On Sunday I let my son watch Netflix on my laptop as I was ill and in bed so couldn't watch it downstairs on the television with him. This may or may not be the root cause of my problem.

Sudo no longer accepts my password. I can log in with my password but I can't sudo. Additionally, if I lock the screen I can't then unlock it with my password. Instead I have to use `switch user`, which presents an identical splash screen to the one for unlocking, but *does* accept my password.

I'm not aware of my son having pressed any buttons while he was watching cartoons, and it would have been one extraordinarily lucky sequence of key presses to do something like this so I'm pretty sure he's not the cause, but include the reference for completeness.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm on 14.04.

The output of `id` is:

```
uid=1000(garry) gid=1000(garry) groups=1000(garry),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Comment: @guntbert Done thanks, it seems to suggest I'm still in `sudo`, but my password works every time for logging in and switching user, but never (since Sunday) for `sudo` or unlocking the screen.

Comment: Next step: what error do you get when calling something with `sudo` (try with `sudo -v`)?

Comment: @guntbert No error, just `Sorry, try again` like the password's wrong. Maddeningly, it randomly worked for a while last night but has now returned to the behaviour described in the question.

Comment: @guntbert nailed it! While typing that comment to you I've found the problem. My keyboard layout, while telling me it's UK English, was in fact Mac or similar (an @ in my password was being passed as a " from the keyboard). Selecting UK english from the keyboard layouts again fixes it. Sounds like time to file a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug. My keyboard layout, though displaying as UK English as normal, was in fact Mac or similar (an @ in my password was being passed as a " from the keyboard). Selecting UK English again from the keyboard layouts in the taskbar fixes it as a workaround. I will investigate the circumstances in which this happens and file a bug.